# Fast switching of logic gates

Tags: logic-gates, switching

I recently heard that at fast switching speeds (rise and fall time in terms of nanoseconds) short circuits can occur inside logic gates. So to prevent damage to the circuit there should be a capacitor connected on the input of gates.

So why exactly do we use a capacitor and why does a short circuit occur?

Comment: you heard wrong

Comment: @Neil_UK: Sorry about it. I have probably overheard few words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're probably referring to is that as CMOS gates transition through the linear region, there is the potential that both top and bottom devices can be on at the same time.  When this happens, the gate can draw a spike of current from the supply.  Because of that, the SUPPLY pins of the IC should be decoupled to ground with one or more capacitors placed as close to the package as possible.  The capacitor is NOT connected to the input of the gates.

Comment: Can that kind of spike damage the inner circuits of the IC?

Comment: In general they are designed so that there can be no damage.  However if the IC is improperly decoupled the part may not function as designed.

Comment: so capacitor can be connected to IC voltage supply pin (closest as it can be to IC PS pin)for preventing malfunctioning of whole IC, right? (to shorten things up)

Comment: That's correct!